# Namenode is notworking

Tags: hadoop

Could you please help me with the issue that I am facing “ NameNode/JobTracker Web UI is not Working”

Existing Hadoop Environment setup

We are given a server, where three vms (with ip series having as 40.40.40.x ) are created and hadoop is installed in it. As these vms are not in my workstation VLAN, for this reason they created public floating  ip(25.20.20.x) for those vms. With these public ips I am able to access to vms from my PC through putty.

Here Hadoop is running fine. I am able create, delete, copy files/directories. When I issue jps command I am to see all the demons like NN, SNN, JT, TT etc.

Problem:

I am  unable to access NameNode/JT web UI from my PC with the url http://25.20.20.x:50070/.

Below are the couple of things I have worked to resolve but did not succeed.

Trails:

1)      I have kept both public and private ips in core-site.xml file

fs.default.name

hdfs://25.20.20.x:54310

Also

fs.default.name

hdfs://40.40.40.x:54310

2)      I have Mapped both public and private ips with hostname in /etc/hosts file and specified host name in core-site file.

/etc/hosts file

40.40.40.x      testDhcp

25.20.20.x    testDhcp

fs.default.name

hdfs://testDhcp:54310

I hope my query is understandable. Please let me know if you require any information.

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the firewall rules that might be preventing you from accessing http://25.20.20.x:50070/
2. Second try logging into your VM with ssh and have a port forwarding set like `ssh -L 50070:localhost:50070 your_user_id@25.20.20.xx` and then access your ui like
   `http://localhost:50070` ....this way you can by pass some of the firewall restrictions.